# smoothing a set point in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I try to smooth R with a set point as follows:

```
myshp <- shapefile("C:/Users/zina/workspace/Proj_Meteo/interpolate/DZA_adm/DZA_adm0.shp")

px<-c(2.7828,2.7828,2.6828,2.5828,2.4828,2.3828,2.3828,2.2828,2.1828,2.0828
      ,1.9828,1.8828,1.7828,1.6828,1.5828,1.4828,1.3828,1.2828,1.1828,1.0828
      ,0.9828,0.8828,0.7828,0.6828,0.5828,0.4828,0.3828,0.2828,0.1828,0.0828
      ,-0.0172,-0.0172,-0.1172,-0.2172,-0.3172,-0.4172,-0.5172,-0.6172,-0.7172,-0.7172
      ,-0.8172,-0.9172,-1.0172,-1.0172,-1.1172,-1.1172,-1.0172,-1.0172,-0.9172,-0.8172
      ,-0.8172,-0.7172,-0.6172,-0.5172,-0.4172,-0.3172,-0.3172,-0.2172,-0.2172,-0.3172
      ,-0.4172,-0.5172,-0.5172,-0.6172,-0.7172,-0.8172,-0.9172,-1.0172,-1.1172,-1.1172
      ,-1.0172,-0.9172,-0.8172,-0.7172,-0.6172,-0.5172,-0.5172,-0.4172,-0.3172,-0.2172
      ,-0.1172,-0.0172,0.0828,0.1828,0.2828,0.3828,0.3828,0.4828,0.5828,0.5828
      ,0.6828,0.7828,0.7828,0.8828,0.9828,1.0828,1.1828,1.2828,1.3828,1.4828
      ,1.5828,1.6828,1.6828,1.7828,1.8828,1.8828,1.9828,2.0828,2.0828,2.1828
      ,2.2828,2.3828,2.4828,2.5828,2.6828,2.7828,2.8828,2.9828,3.0828,3.1828
      ,3.2828,3.3828,3.4828,3.5828,3.6828,3.7828,3.8828,3.9828,4.0828,4.1828
      ,4.2828,4.3828,4.4828,4.5828,4.6828,4.7828,4.8828,4.9828,5.0828,5.1828
      ,5.2828,5.3828,5.4828,5.5828,5.6828,5.7828,5.8828,5.9828,5.9828,5.9828
      ,5.8828,5.7828,5.7828,5.7828,5.6828,5.5828,5.4828,5.3828,5.2828,5.1828
      ,5.0828,4.9828,4.9828,4.8828,4.7828,4.6828,4.6828,4.5828,4.4828,4.4828
      ,4.3828,4.2828,4.2828,4.1828,4.0828,3.9828,3.9828,3.8828,3.7828,3.6828
      ,3.5828,3.4828,3.3828,3.3828,3.2828,3.1828,3.0828,3.0828,2.9828,2.8828
      ,2.7828)
py<-c(32.3764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764
      ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764
      ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764 ,31.5764
      ,31.5764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,31.9764 ,32.3764
      ,32.3764 ,32.3764 ,32.3764 ,32.7764 ,32.7764 ,33.1764 ,33.1764 ,33.5764 ,33.5764 ,33.5764
      ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,34.3764 ,34.3764 ,34.7764 ,34.7764
      ,34.7764 ,34.7764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.5764
      ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764
      ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,36.3764 ,36.3764 ,36.3764 ,35.9764
      ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.5764
      ,35.5764 ,35.5764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,36.3764 ,36.3764 ,36.3764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764
      ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764
      ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764
      ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764
      ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.7764 ,36.3764 ,35.9764
      ,35.9764 ,35.9764 ,35.5764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,35.1764
      ,35.1764 ,35.1764 ,34.7764 ,34.7764 ,34.7764 ,34.7764 ,34.3764 ,34.3764 ,34.3764 ,33.9764
      ,33.9764 ,33.9764 ,33.5764 ,33.5764 ,33.5764 ,33.5764 ,33.1764 ,33.1764 ,33.1764 ,33.1764
      ,33.1764 ,33.1764 ,33.1764 ,32.7764 ,32.7764 ,32.7764 ,32.7764 ,32.3764 ,32.3764 ,32.3764,32.3764)


      require(Hmisc) #for Bezier curve

      bz <- bezier(px,py)
      plot(myshp)
      poly<-polygon(bz$x,bz$y, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),border=NA)
```

Here's the resulat, smoothing is not currently adequatea rectangle that spell I don't understand its origin.
[image: result]

Can someone tell me the problem because I can't manage to capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a smaller `evaluation`, e.g.:

```
bz <- bezier(px, py, evaluation=50)
```

It's because the `const <- (1 - z)^(n - 1)` part of `bezier` evaluates to zero near the end of the evaluation points. [It doesn't look like a particularly stable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37TRz.png), but I can't say that I know the [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) algorithms. Consider notifying the maintainer of Hmisc of this behaviour.

Comment: ultimately it's a stupid thing that I stayed all day looking for !! big thank you @Mike T